# How to make a greeting card application

Tags: android, templates, bitmap, android-bitmap

It may look like a duplicate but please first go through the question. I have checked all the SO questions regarding my query. If you find any similar query, I'll be happy to see that question.

> I am creating an android app which has one feature, almost same as that required for a greeting card app.
>
> Lets say I am making a greeting card app, in which there is a predefined layout with flowers in the background and a space where you can write "Happy Birthday" and then there is one more space where you can write your "Name".
>
> Now what should happen is, whenever user clicks on the save button an image should get saved at some place [that we can decide later]. So the card, in the form of an image should be created {jpg or img}.
>
> The solution that I have right now is to make everything on a canvas bitmap and OnClick save the bitmap but it become really difficult for multiple screens. Also the image doesn't comes out to be as expected.

Please lead me as how you can load any templates and allow the user to edit some text in the template to create greeting card image.

Thanks. Please comment if any part of the question is not clear.

Comment: @Eypros - As explained above, what I do is that there is canvas where a bitmap is shown with an image background. Then there are some editText boxes where the user writes "Happy birthday". When the user clicks on the save button. The bitmap is saved. The concept is almost same as that of the Screenshot, where I take a screenshot and then cut the image from borders to get the greeting card. But it is not scalable solution for all screen sizes and different card layouts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the track with you present solution. I would keep doing all of it on the Canvas but put that code inside a custom ImageView class (make a new class in which you extend `ImageView`). You can then set the dimensions of the Bitmap this class produces to something standard (not dependent on screen size). You can then add this custom ImageView to your XML layout and use `CENTER_INSIDE` scaling on the view so it scale up/down as appropriate for the device's screen size.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution, such as use of some library or template which can be loaded for such dynamic texts. Also I would like to add a small image inside the card where the user can put his/her group photo (or whatever). How to move forward regarding that ? Thanks for the help btw.